# MAAS deployment without formatting secondary disks

Tags: ubuntu, cluster

I manage a cluster of computers used for scientific computing using MAAS 2.1.  Each node has a 500GB SDD that holds the OS and servers as scratch space for computation.  Additionally, each node has a secondary 5TB disk that holds several terabytes of data.

I've noticed that when I release and deploy a machine (with the MAAS UI), all disks get formatted.

Is there any way to prevent MAAS from formatting the 5TB HDDs when I have to redeploy a machine?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm very interested in this as well. Though, in my case, I want to partition a single 1TB SSD into two partitions and keep the second one's data across release - deploy cycles.

Answer (score 3):

This may be unsatisfying (it certainly was for me), but what I ended up doing was to delete the disks in the MAAS interface; if MAAS doesn't know about these volumes then it doesn't format them at any point.  Of course, deleting them doesn't change anything about what the OS sees, so I was able to put in the necessary partitioning/fs creation stuff in our provisioning scripts.